# how to hide or disabled particular ng-repeat div in particular user profile using angullarjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have created 3 coupons.1st one is applicable for 10 user,2nd one is applicable for 5 user and 3rd one is applicable for 20 user.In user page i have listed coupons with activate button using ng-repeat.if once user activates coupon i have stored coupon id and coupondetails in one table and i have reduced the count in coupons for example user activated 1st coupon in that count(10) i have reduced 1 and 9 coupons remaining its working fine. Expectation: If once user activated the coupon i want to remove activated coupon div from ng-repeat in his/her profile or i need to change button status Activated and disabled link

```js
.controller('CouponsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$ionicPopup','$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $location, $ionicPopup,$ionicLoading) {  
       $scope.find = function() {
          $http.get('').success(function(data, dealers, response) {
              $scope.coupons = data;  
          });
       }
    }
])
```

```html
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="coupon in coupons |  filter:couponquery ">

  <div class="item item-body" style="padding:10px;">
    <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{coupon.Coupon_Image}}">
    <p style="color:green;font-weight:700">
    {{coupon.Store_Name}}
    </p>
   <p style="font-weight:700">{{coupon.Offer_Meassage}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left" >
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="apply(coupon._id,coupon.Store_ID)" id="appcolor">
      <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> 
      Activate
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

in that particular profile any one help me out. i am new to this technology dont give down vote my plunkar http://jsfiddle.net/sreemohan143/U3pVM/18537/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hope it helps...
    
    
        List Of students

```
    <div ng-repeat="coupon in coupons | filter:search | filter:{'activated':false}" style="border-radius:5px;background: #8AC007;padding: 20px;">
        <br>{{coupon.couponname}}
        <br>
        <br>{{coupon.offermessage}}

     <a class="tab-item" ng-click="activate(coupon)" id="appcolor">
  <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> 
  Activate
</a>
    </div>
</div>
<BR>
<BR>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.coupons = [{

    id: "1",
    couponname: "healthy breakfast offer",
    offermessage: "50% offer for break fast",
    noofcoupon: "10",
    activated: false
}, {
     id: "2",
    couponname: "get 50% lunch",
    offermessage: "50% offer for Lunch",
    noofcoupon: "10",
    activated: false
}, {
     id: "3",
    couponname: "dinner damaka",
    offermessage: "50% offer for dinner",
    noofcoupon: "10",
    activated: false
}

]

 $scope.activate = function(coupon) {
coupon.noofcoupon--;
coupon.activated = true;
 }

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/712u24m2/

Comment: expectation once activated i need to hide div .when ever user comes its should be unvisible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` to determine if it is activated or not and in your coupons objects add a key activated.

and in html `ng-show= !activated`

In your click function you can change the activated attribute

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/42ckr88y/4/

Comment: expectation once activated i need to hide div .when ever user comes its should be unvisible